# Load Page resources (.css, .js) from fake/local path

Tags: javascript, css, networking, localhost

My page is working fine in the development environment and having a JS syntax error on staging environment. All JS files are minified on staging and we cannot do debugging on client side in the minified JS. I have tried the "Pretty print" option but still cannot debug the page load JavaScript.

My Question is that how can I manipulate my computer to get the .js file from local machine instead of server. For example if page need `http://server.com/page.js` It should load it from `http://localhost/page.js`.

I have updated the host file to add the domain for files which are coming from different CDNs and they are working fine e.g. for jquery I have added `**googleapis.com**` entry to host file and it started getting that file from my local machine.

I am not sure how to do it for files which are hosted on the same server as the page is?

We are using proprietary Minify tools which executes on post build events of Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at how to create *.map files for minified javascript.
In Visual Studio this is easy with WebEssentials.

If you don't have a native solution in your software somewhere, the cumbersome part is to setup nodejs and then configure + run a plugin.

To get you an idea:

- https://raygun.io/blog/2014/02/getting-started-with-javascript-source-maps/
- https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/05/compiling-to-javascript-and-debugging-with-source-maps/

Not sure about your project setup and/or server language. In .Net MVC the minifying part is done by the BundleConfig. I can then set in the Web.Config `debug=true` so it doesn't minify.
Since you are talking about "staging" it's still ok to debug on a staging environment imho.

Comment: No Access to staging enviroment

Comment: You are building to staging, are you not? You can setup your solution with publishing profiles. Set the proper config values for each profile. Overwrite the debug attr for the staging profile and you're good to go.